# Hadoop mapper phase stuck after 19% In which case this possibility can occur?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

My MapReduce program is running fine with other MR code. There is no error in the code. Still it is getting stuck.

```
15/05/28 19:53:29 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
15/05/28 19:53:31 INFO mapred.JobClient: Running job: job_201504101709_0927
15/05/28 19:53:32 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 0% reduce 0%
15/05/28 19:53:46 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 19% reduce 0%
15/05/28 20:03:50 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 0% reduce 0%
15/05/28 20:03:51 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201504101709_0927_m_000000_0, Status : FAILED
Task attempt_201504101709_0927_m_000000_0 failed to report status for 602 seconds. Killing!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible reason for this might be a bug in Mapper, like an infinite loop.  Just check if everything is fine in Mapper. If you feel its not problem, update your question with your mapper code.